# BeautifulSoup with python - parsing misses certain tags

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing SGML documents using BeautifulSoup and the lmxl parser.

I parse the SGML and then use BeautifulSoup to examine the tree for various conditions that need to be corrected. When I find a condition, I want to determine if it is a child of a tag `revst`.

When I find the condition and iterate over `.parents` I do not find the `<revst>` as a parent even though on examining the document the `<revst>` is there in the tree.

If I call `soup('revst')`, all of the `revst` are identified and can be manipulated.

I've tried `lxml`, `xml`, and `html5lib` parsers and they all miss `revst` as a parent.

I can think of two ways to correct this problem:

1. Add `revst` to the BeautifulSoup library so it will be identified in `.parents`
2. Compare `soup.revst` with `soup.elementIcareAbout.name` to see if one is the child

I am unclear on how to execute either of these approaches.  Are there other options for handling this?

I've also tried `etree` to parse but get parsing errors...

Here is the code I am using:

```
x=soup('extref')
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    for parent in x[i].parents:
        r = parent.name
        print(r)
```

r then gives me the list of parent tags for each element found in x.

This list should include 'revst' for some of the elements but does not.

Comment: The description of your problem, which you have provided, would be easier to follow if you included your code.

Comment: Good point.  Sorry.

Comment: Brian, you wouldn't have a sample SGML document of the kind you're interest in that you could post on pastebin, would you? To let me know in a comment, type the 'at' key for a menu.

Comment: @Bill -- I will need to create a generic example to upload.

Comment: Should be interesting.